# Activating Users' mobile phone camera Documents mode in App

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, kotlin

**Background**

I am building an Optical Character Recognition (**OCR**) tool that makes sense of photographed Forms.

Arguably the most complicated part of the pipeline is to get the target Document into perspective; basically what is attempted in [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) Tutorial.

Due to the fact that the data is acquired often in very poor conditions, i.e.:

- Uncontrolled Brightness
- Covered or removed corners
- Background containing more texture than the Target Document
- Shades
- Overlapped Documents

I have "solved" the Problem using Instance + Semantic Segmentation.

**Situation**

The images are uploaded by Users via an App that captures images as is. There are versions for the App in both Android and IOS.

**Question**

Would it be possible to force the App to use the Users' mobile phone *Documents* mode (if present) prior to acquiring the photo?

The objective is to simplify the pipeline.

In end effect, at a description level, the App would have to do three things:

1 - Activate the *Documents* mode

[image]

2 - Outline the Target Document; if possible even showing the yellow frame.

[image]

3 - Upload the processed file to the server. Orientation and extension are not important.

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? Stack Overflow is not a coding service platform

Comment: The question is: Would it be possible to force the App to use the Users' mobile phone Documents mode (if present) prior to acquiring the photo?

Comment: What document mode? It is not a native function in iOS / Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### iOS

This isn't a "mode" for the native camera app.

### Android

There isn't a way to have the the "documents mode" automatically selected. This isn't available for all Android devices, either. So even if you could, it wouldn't be reliable.

Best bet is following the documentation for [Building a camera app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#custom-camera), rather than using the native camera if special document scanning is essential. This won't come out of the box on either platform for you.